# Persist an entity object to HDFS using spark

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I have a person object as shown below:

`Person person = new Person();
 person.setPersonId("10");
 person.setAge(20);`

I want to save it in HDFS using Spark. It can be done using save method of DataFrame class in spark as shown below:

`dataFrame.save("hdfs://localhost:9000/sample.json");`

but I have not find any method to convert entity object to `RDD` or `DataFrame`

Is there any way to convert entity object to RDD or DataFrame?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest your to convert Person object to List.
And SparkContext can use "parallelize" api to convert List be RDD.
And a RDD can use "saveAsObjectFile" api to save to hdfs by sequence file.
I suppose you coding with Java. This is a sample code as below.

```
  SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkSaveToHDFS");
 JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

 Person Peter = new Person();
 Peter.setName("Peter");
 Peter.setAge(30);
 Person Kevin = new Person();
 Kevin.setName("Kevin");
 Kevin.setAge(40);

 List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
 personList.add(0, Peter);
 personList.add(1,Kevin);
 System.out.println("list contains Peter : " + personList.contains(Peter) + Peter.getAge());
 System.out.println("list contains Kevin : " + personList.contains(Kevin) + Kevin.getAge());

 JavaRDD<Person> personRdd = ctx.parallelize(personList);
 personRdd.saveAsObjectFile("hdfs://hadoop-master:8020/Peter/test");
```

And final use SparkContext "objectFile" api to get hdfs entity to RDD.
Sample code as below

```
 JavaRDD<Person> getPersonRdd = ctx.objectFile("hdfs://hadoop-master:8020/Peter/test");
    DataFrame schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(getPersonRdd, Person.class);
    schemaPeople.registerTempTable("people");
    schemaPeople.printSchema();
    DataFrame people = sqlContext.sql("select * from people");
    people.show();
```